# Docker on raspbian will not run containers

Tags: linux, docker, raspbian, raspberry-pi-zero, zim-database

here’s my situation. I’m very inexperienced with any OS that isn’t windows. I’m working on a Raspberry Pi Zero W running Raspbian, with the ultimate goal of running zimdump so I can edit .zim files. A [tutorial](https://www.google.com/amp/s/codeablereason.wordpress.com/2016/04/09/how-to-build-zimdump-to-process-zim-files/amp/) includes the use of Docker to mount the .zim file as a volume and work within a container. I seemed to have installed Docker with the correct version and architecture, but `docker run hello-world` doesn’t work as expected. Log from the first time I ran it:

```
Unable to find image ‘hello-world:latest‘ locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
4ee5c797bcd7: Pull complete
Digest: sha256: [long sha256]
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world: latest
```

And nothing else. I ran it a second time, and nothing printed. The third time, I ran

```
sudo docker run hello-world -it
```

which printed more verbosely

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused “exec: \”-it\”: executable file not found in $PATH”: unknown.
```

I tried an assortment of troubleshooting steps, from users whose situations were only related to mine, but not exactly, and I don’t want to alter anything else behind the scenes that makes this harder for you and me.
Here’s my `docker info`:

```
Client:
  Debug Mode: false

Server:
  Containers: 3
    Running: 0
    Paused: 0
    Stopped: 3
  Images: 1
  Server Version: 19.03.12
  Storage Driver: overlay2
    Backing Filesystem: extfs 
    Supports d_type: true
    Native Overlay Diff: true
  Logging Driver: json-file
  Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
  Plugins:
    Volume: local
    Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
    Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog 
  Swarm: inactive
  Runtimes: runc 
  Init Binary: docker-init
  containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
  runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
  init version: fec3683
  Security Options:
    seccomp 
      Profile: default
  Kernel Version: 4.19.66+
  Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
  OSType: Linux
  Architecture: armv6l
  CPUs: 1
  Total Memory: 424.8MiB
  Name: box.lan
  ID: DAJU:334L:G6WP:RARN:REWW:K2LE:CJUK:LCBJ:XDWH:ZX5D:4XRM:BCTM
  Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
  Debug Mode: false
  Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1s/
  Labels:
  Experimental: false
  Insecure Registries:
    127.0.0.0/8
  Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
WARNING: No cpuset support
```

I’ve spent 8 hours on this, and all I want to do is remove explicit wikipedia pages from the .zim so we can give this raspberry pi to kids as an offline internet.

You all are the best ☺️

Comment: Drop the `-it`. Try: `docker run hello-world`

Comment: and `-it` goes before container name. So it's `docker run -ti hello-world`.

Comment: @kaylum this still prints nothing :( @KamilCuk `docker run -it hello-world` printed `failed to resize tty, using default size`, and then one more line of whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

The regular version of hello-world Dock image won't work on a Raspberry Pi zero. Because Raspberry Pi zero uses ARMv6Z instruction sets. Instead of `docker run hello-world`, you can run:

`docker run --name someContainerName arm32v5/hello-world`

Notice that this container was built with ARM32v5 instruction set. In theory, any ARM32 version equal to or below v6 should work on a Pi zero.

It took me a whole day to figure out. I've written a [blog post](https://lokarithm.com/2020/05/31/how-to-run-docker-on-your-raspberry-pi-in-2020/) on how to get Docker working on a Raspberry Pi 1 and Zero if you want to learn about the detail.